# How to update Activerrecord fields dynamiclly?

Tags: ruby, activerecord, dynamic

I need update some fields in activerecord model. But I'll get model and names/values of fields only at runntime. Some of the fields are the other models and associations has already set up.

The best solution I could come up with is:

```
fields.each do |key,val|
  model.send :"#{key}, val
end
```

Is there any other method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without save, [attributes=](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/attributes=):

```
model.attributes = fields
```

With save and validation, [update_attributes](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update_attributes):

```
model.update_attributes(fields)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
fields.each do |key,val|
  model.update_attribute key, val
end
```

or

```
model.update_attributes fields
```